# Matrix Multiplication question

Tags: c, matrix

So I'm trying to write a C function to calculate the multiplication of two arrays but I am a little bit stuck.

```
double ** matrixMultiply(double **A, int nRowsOfA, int nColsOfA,
double **B, int nRowsOfB, int nColsOfB)
{

    double **out;
    int i, j, l;

    out=(double **)malloc(nRowsOfA*sizeof(double *));
    for (i=0;i<nRowsOfA; i++)
        out[i]=(double *)malloc(nColsOfB*sizeof(double));



    for (i=0;i<nRowsOfA; i++)
        for (j=0; j<nColsOfB; j++)
        {
          Some calculation to figure out how to multiply the two matrices together.
        }
    return out;

}
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with creating a 2-D array from i and j, but yeah, I'm not sure how to execute it.

Comment: can you explain what problem you are facing

Comment: Please be more sprcific on what exatly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrices are `A` and `B`, and `AB = C`, the entry `C[i][j]` is given by:

```
A[i][1] x B[1][j] + A[i][2] x B[2][j] + A[i][3] x B[3][j] ...
```

So:

1. You will want to check that `nColsOfA == nRowsOfB`, since otherwise the multiplication is not defined.
2. You will want `C` to have `nRowsofA` rows and `nColsOfB` columns.
3. You will want another loop inside the inner loop in your code, to calculate the sum above for each `C[i][j]`.  This will loop over the values `0` to `nColsofA - 1`.